# How do I determine whether open socket is TCP or unix domain socket?

Tags: sockets, tcp, unix-socket

My code is passed an open socket. This socket could be either a TCP socket (`AF_INET`) or a Unix Domain Socket (`AF_UNIX`).

Depending on the domain of the socket, it will need to be handled differently. In particular if the socket is bound to an address then I might want to `accept` incoming connections in a diffent way.

What is the best way to determine whether the socket I have been passed is a unix domain socket or a TCP socket? The solution would need to work on OS X and Linux at least.

`getsockopt` appears to allow getting the type of the socket (e.g. `SOCK_STREAM` etc) but not the domain.

`getsockname` will return a zero length for unix domain sockets on OSX, but this is officially a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getsockname.2.html) and the Linux behaviour is [different](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first member of the `struct sockaddr` returned by `getsockname` is `sa_family`, just test that against the symbolic constants.  The bug on OSX lets you assume the unix domain when the returned address structure is zero bytes, for other platforms and domains, just check the returned structure.

Answer (score 1):

`getsockname()` is the only cross-platform socket API to query a socket for its locally bound address, and thus its address family.

On Windows, at least, you can use `getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_PROTOCOL_INFO)` to retrieve a [`WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741675.aspx) struct, which has an `iAddressFamily` field.  Maybe there are similar platform-specific APIs on other OSes.